# Trying to remove object throws error 1009 cannot access a property or method of null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Working on a flash game, in a previous game I had enemies come in by using an array and when they were killed or moved off the stage I would just remove them from the array.   For some reason when I use exactly the same code in this game, it throws a 1009: error when I try to remove the array object, basically saying that there's nothing there.   . . Which is strange.

Here's the code:

```
public function addZombie()
{
    var zom:Zombie = new Zombie();
    zom.y = 20;
    zom.x = Math.floor(Math.random()*(1 + 500 - 30)) + 30;
    addChild(zom);
    zombies.push(zom);
    numZombies++;
}
```

That's the function where it's added in, zombies is the array and it's pushed into the array in this function.  Here's the code where I'm attempting to remove it:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < zombies.length; i++)
{
    if (zombies[i].y + zombies[i].height / 2 > 400) {
        removeChild(zombies[i]);
        zombies.splice(i,1);
        numZombies--;
        addZombie();
    }
}
```

removeChild(zombies[i]); <-- This is the part that throws the error when it attempts to remove it.  It removes some of them strangely enough, but not all of them.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me that `removeChild(zombies[i]);` is the line that throws the error. That would mean that `zombies[i]` is `null` which can't be the case as your test on the previous line already use it without any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe the loop is doing quite what you expect it to.  When you remove an element from an array in this way, all the elements after the removed elements are moved down.  So, if you have code like:

```
var testArr:Array = new Array();
testArr.push('First');
testArr.push('Second');
testArr.push('Third');
testArr.push('Fourth');

for (var i:int = 0; i < testArr.length; i++) {
    testArr.splice(i,1);
}
```

The results of the loop will be:

```
i=0, testArr = ['Second', 'Third', 'Fourth']
i=1, testArr = ['Second', 'Fourth']
i=2 END OF LOOP
```

It would probably be better to use a while loop, incrementing the index only if the element is not removed (since removing the element moves a new element to that index position).

I don't see why you're getting the null object reference, but this would be causing other problems (why some are removed but not all).

Comment: A while loop does remove them all, but it still throws null object references every time.

Comment: As stated below figured out the null, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The explanations of Bill Turner are the correct ones, but as it didn't seem to help you fix your issue, you might want to try this:

```
var zombieCount:int = zombies.length;

for (var i:int = 0; i < zombies.length; i++)
{
    var zombie = zombies[i];
    if (zombie.y + (zombie.height / 2) > 400) {
        removeChild(zombie);
        zombies.splice(i,1);
        i--; // So that the loop will pass with the same value next time
        numZombies--;
    }
}

for (var j:int = zombies.length; j < zombieCount; j++)
{
    addZombie();
}
```

Comment: Did try it, unfortunately I still get the same null object error.

Comment: Tried it and it is still triggered at the removeChild step.   If I comment that out, no errors trigger at all.   If I comment out absolutely anything else, the errors still trigger.

Comment: I fixed it, the error was actually in the code for the zombie itself and not in there at all, can't believe I didn't think about that before.  I forgot to remove the EnterFrame when the zombie is removed.  Thank you for your help.